# Initialize classes in their own interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I looked at some code and noticed such construction:

```
public interface TestIntrerface {
  void doFirst();
  void doSecond();
}

public interface Interface1 extends TestIntrerface {
  Interface1 inter = new FirstClass();
}

public interface Interface2 extends TestIntrerface {
  Interface2 intr = new SecondClass();
}


public class FirstClass implements Interface1 {
  public void doFirst() {
    //...
  }

   public void doSecond() {
      //...
   }
}

public class SecondClass implements Interface2 {
   public void doFirst() {
      //...
   }

  public void doSecond() {
      //...
  }
}


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface1.inter.doFirst();
    Interface2.intr.doSecond();
  }
}
```

It has the potential for me but I've never seen that construct before. 
Two questions:

1. What is the name of this pattern (is that pattern(?))?
2. It is a good practice to use this in the real world?

Comment: well you have to do some reading about interfaces. and thing that you call Pattern is just simple variable declaration, if you do reading, you would know, variables in interface are initialized because they are public static final by default, Object you are creating with reference is same as creating public static final int SOMETHING  = 1; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an example of two [constant declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) `inter` and `intr` in interfaces. It's not a pattern and I wouldn't say it's a good practice.

1. `Interface1` and `Interface2` are meaningless: they don't complement/implement the interfaces they extend. Basically, they are holders of the constants that could have been defined somewhere else. Note that the constants are bound to particular classes while interfaces carry a broader sense, provide a general interface.
2. The names `inter` and `intr` are terrible and they don't tell what those constants represent/do.

A more justifiable example would look like

```
interface TestInterface {
  void doFirst();
  void doSecond();

  TestInterface EMPTY = new TestInterface() {
    @Override
    public void doFirst() {}
    @Override
    public void doSecond() {}
  };

}
```

where `EMPTY` tells that it's a default (and empty) implementation of the interface. Notice that I called it `EMPTY` (not `empty`) because it's always a `public static final` field.